# awaiting future never reached, although set_result() is called

Tags: python, python-asyncio

My example class uses only two methods,

- `async def run()`: creates a asyncio.Future() and awaits it
- `def stop()`: sets the result of the Future() created by the run() method

The idea is to use the python signal handler to call the `stop()` function once a signal is received. The `stop()` then sets the result of the Future() the `run()` is waiting for. So far so good, but this does not work. Actually, the `run()` method never notices that the Future() is done.

Example code:

```
import asyncio
import signal


class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._stop = None

    async def run(self):
        print(f"1. starting foo")
        self._stop = asyncio.Future()
        await self._stop
        print(f"4. 'stop' called, canceling running tasks...")

    def stop(self):
        print(f"3. stopping foo")
        self._stop.set_result(None)


f = Foo()
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()


def signal_handler(_, __):
    print(f"2. signal handler: call Foo.stop()")
    f.stop()


signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
loop.run_until_complete(f.run())
print(f"5. bye")
```

and the output is:

```
1. starting foo
2. signal handler: call Foo.stop()
3. stopping foo
```

That's it. The fourth print entry is never called. Although the `self._stop` Future is `done` after setting the result.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong and what I am missing?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem, but it is quite possible that it'll happen on different operating systems.

Per [loop.add_signal_handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.add_signal_handler):

> Unlike signal handlers registered using `signal.signal()`, a callback registered with this function is allowed to interact with the event loop.

The usual culprit that causes those issues is the event loop not waking up from outside input.

There are 2 solutions for your issue:

1. If you're using unix, change `signal.signal()` to `loop.add_signal_handler()`.
2. If not, try changing `f.stop()` to `loop.call_soon_threadsafe(f.stop)`. It will make sure that the event loop wakes up correctly.

Irrespective to that, you have a couple of different issues arising from using `asyncio.new_event_loop()` and not assigning the loop to the thread or cleaning up correctly. I suggest you to use `asyncio.run()`.

Comment: `loop.call_soon_threadsafe(f.stop)` does the job! Both solutions work perfectly, than you very much.